# Extend surround code in Netbeans for basic HTML tags

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I efficiently surround multiple lines of code in the Netbeans IDE?

For example, for the following code...

```
First link
Second link
Third link
```

... I want to a quick and easy way to transform it to be:

```
<li><a href="${cursor}">First link</a></li>
<li><a href="${cursor}">Second link</a></li>
<li><a href="${cursor}">Third link</a></li>
```

This is possible in other editors. In Sublime Text, for example, you can select all the lines, use the "Split into Lines" command, then the "Wrap selection with Tag" command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use search and replace.

It is easy to mess up regular expressions so save your text file first.

Use Edit -> Replace menu option or Ctrl-H to bring up replace bar.

Set Find What to `(.*)\n`
Set Replace With to `<li><a href=\"\$\{cursor\}\">$1</a></li>\n`

Notice that I need to escape several of the special characters.
Make sure the toggle-button for Regular Expression is set.
With the text selected you can click the Replace All Button. Or just replace one at a time with replace button.

[image: replace bar screenshot]

It can also be done with rectangular cut and paste.

Copy and paste a number of times to create this in a text file.

```
<li><a href="${cursor}"></a></li>
<li><a href="${cursor}"></a></li>
<li><a href="${cursor}"></a></li>
```

Toggle rectangular selection using the toggle-button at top of editor.

[image: toggle-rectangular selection button]

Copy a rectangle around your set of links and then select another rectangle in the block of empty list elements and paste.